# Express route has empty body always

Tags: node.js, angular

I have a REST API using `Node.js` and `Express.js`. I am using an `Angular5` application to consume the REST API. With regard to making the API call from Angular application, it done via a service and the code is as follows:

`auth.service.ts`:

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post( environment.baseUrl + '/api/v1/login', JSON.stringify({ email: email, password: password }))
      .map((response: Response) => {
        let user = response.json();
        if (user && user.token) {
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
        }
      });
  }
```

In my Node's `app.ts`, the application is defined as follows:

`app.ts`:

```
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  // Website you wish to allow to connect
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,__setXHR_');
  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next();
});
```

And if you look at the controllers, here is the code:

```
login = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    this.model.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, (err, user) => {
      if (!user) { return res.sendStatus(403); }
      user.comparePassword(req.body.password, (error, isMatch) => {
        if (!isMatch) { return res.sendStatus(403); }
        const token = jwt.sign({ user: user }, process.env.SECRET_TOKEN); // , { expiresIn: 10 } seconds
        res.status(200).json({ token: token });
      });
    });
  }
```

I get a 403 error and below is what is printed on my console:

```
[2] {}
[2] {}
[2] POST /api/v1/login 403 22.004 ms - 9
```

I can pretty much see the request body being sent in my chrome debugger.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is in req.body ?

Comment: Please provide more debugging info regarding req.body , user and isMatch values in login controller.

Comment: `this.http.post` doesn't return a promise ? `map` should not be replaced by `then` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I was using `JSON.stringify(<data>)` in my post request. I had to send the object and not the JSON string. On removing it, it worked.

Comment: Kind of rude to just delete your question from today (12/10) while I'm working on it with you.  If you find you think you need to delete it, you can at least leave a comment and let me see it (before deleting it) so I know why.